# Open Excel file as Read-Only, Discard changes opon closing or Save as

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel template/report that I don't want users to modify

I saved the template as `Read-Only Recommended`  (save as -. tools -> general options) so users are prompted to open as read-only, and are forced to save another copy if modified.

However, I was hoping to remove the prompt, so file open easily accessed without having to click another button

How effectively can I do this?

I tested adding the following to `ThisWorkbook` module so code is invoked upon opening

```
Private Sub OpenWorkBookReadOnly()
    ThisWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadOnly
End Sub
```

While it works i.e file changes to `Read-only` upon opening, however it means users will never be able to easily save the documents as long as the VBA codes lives in the workbook

What I want to achieve is this:

1. Template file opens as read-only (hopefully without having to click a button)
2. Users are prompted to `save as` when there are changes to template
3. When users saves a copy, templates read-only (and other) properties doesn't affects this copy.

Comment: Right-click the file and mark as read-only in the Properties dialog ?

Comment: That's a smart one, I'll test this now. Potential problem is users can amend this attribute on the original file

Comment: In that case it would be best to store it somewhere where they have read-only access, or maybe host it on a web server (not knowing your environment makes if harder to know which of those would be workable...)

Comment: It's in a remote desktop - RDS environment, I can dump the templates in a  folder where users have only read-access, they'll have to navigate to their own folder to be able to save a copy, grea and thanks.